# error while getting asr replication items details in azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm using azure PowerShell to get the replicated item details using the below code, as per the documentation the program is correct but it's giving an error as below.

```
$VaultName = 'Site-recovery-vault-westus'
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $VaultName
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
$fabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric
$container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container
```

At 5th line Error: Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.ASRFabric' required by parameter 'Fabric'. Specified method is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested in  our local environment, Below observations are based on your analysis.

By using the shared cmdlets, we able to pull the `AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer` in the recovery service vault.

> $fabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric

As per the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/get-azrecoveryservicesasrfabric?view=azps-6.5.0#example-1), `Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric`  Returns all the Azure Site Recovery fabrics in the vault.

> Error: Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer: Cannot convert
> 'System.Object[]' to the type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.ASRFabric'

if you have more than one Fabric in your recovery service vault the above error occurs. while fetching the `AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer`

We would suggest you  to pass the Fabric Name as parameter  to $fabric Variable to fetch `Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer` under that particular Fabric.

Here is the reference output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I can able to retrieve the data now, I'm looking for storage account details used in the ASR. but I don't see any method in the documentation.

Comment: able to get VMl licycle id, but I'm looking for cache storage account details.

Comment: foreach ($replicationProtectedItem in $replicationProtectedItems) {
 $vmId = $replicationProtectedItem.ProviderSpecificDetails.LifecycleId
 Write-Output "The ID of the protected item $($replicationProtectedItem.FriendlyName) is $vmId"
}

Comment: @venkatesDodda-MT

Comment: @ValakatlaAshok, You question is addressed  over this SO Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672548/asr-replication-storage-account-details-on-protected-items-powershell/69675825#69675825