# ASR Replication storage account details on protected items PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

Unable to get the cache storage account used in the ASR replicated items. Able to get the health status, replication Ids.

This is the code I used:

```
$VaultName = 'Site-recovery-vault-westus'
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $VaultName
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
$fabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric -Name asr-a2a-default-eastus
$container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
$replicationProtectedItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container

foreach ($replicationProtectedItem in $replicationProtectedItems) {
    $vmId = $replicationProtectedItem.ProviderSpecificDetails.LifecycleId
    Write-Output "The ID of the protected item $($replicationProtectedItem.FriendlyName) is $vmId"
}

foreach ($replicationProtectedItem in $replicationProtectedItems) {
    $cachesaId = $replicationProtectedItem.providerSpecificDetails.protectedManagedDisks.primaryStagingAzureStorageAccountId
    Write-Output "The cache sa of the protected item $($replicationProtectedItem.FriendlyName) is $cachesaId"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have tested in our local environment, below observations are based on our analysis.

We tried pulling the Cached storage account details using cmdlet `Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem`. Generally storage account details will get populated under the `providerspecificdetails.primaryStagingAzureStorageAccountId` property but unfortunately using PowerShell we are not able to pull the cache storage account details.

Alternatively you can use this [Replication Protected Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wm4z.png) Azure Management Rest API to pull the cache storage account details.

Below is the sample output for reference:

[image]